# springxd stream creation failed due to transform groovy script

Tags: groovy, cassandra, spring-xd

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I want to create streams using springXD. According to basic definition of streams,          I have:

```
Source :  http

Transform script : I written one groovy script which I stored at 
/xd/modules/processor/script/transform.groovy            

Sink : cassandra
```

I want to store the  unstructured json data, which I posted from http to cassandra table.
I run springXD on single-node mode, and then run xd-shell.
For stream creation, I use:

```
stream create --name test2 --definition "http --port=9000 | transform --   
script=insert_transform.groovy |cassandra --contactPoints=127.0.0.1 --
keyspace=db1 --ingestQuery='insert into table1 (emp_id,emp_name,amount,time)
values (?,?,?,?)'" –deploy
```

I got message:
Created and deployed new stream 'test2'

After that when I am posting data through http it gives following errors:

```
500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

On the xd-singlenode, following error log appears:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [insert_transform.groovy] cannot be opened because it does not exist.
```

Comment: I believe `/xd/modules/processor/script` should be `/xd/modules/processor/scripts` (with plural `scripts`)

Comment: still getting the same error. using springXD 1.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Spring XD? I just tested it with 1.3.0.RELEASE and it worked fine...

```
xd:>stream create foo --definition "time | transform --script=test.groovy | log" --deploy
```

.

```
$ cat xd/modules/processor/scripts/test.groovy
'Time = ' + payload
```

.

```
2016-01-11T09:45:19-0500 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO xdbus.foo.1-1 sink.foo - Time = 2016-01-11 09:45:19
2016-01-11T09:45:20-0500 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO xdbus.foo.1-1 sink.foo - Time = 2016-01-11 09:45:20
2016-01-11T09:45:21-0500 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO xdbus.foo.1-1 sink.foo - Time = 2016-01-11 09:45:21
```

Comment: I have attached an image of error log. I am using springXD 1.3.0 on my local system, running xd as singlenode. OS- ubuntu14.04 lts, and cassandra also running on local host on my virtual machine.

Comment: Did you try my simple(r) test case? I just noticed you said you are putting the script at `/xd/...`; it should be `<xd-install-dir>/spring-xd-1.3.0.RELEASE/xd/...` where `<xd-install-dir>` is where you unzipped the archive. i.e. `$XD_HOME/xd/...`.

Comment: I am new to springXD, sorry to say but I am unable to understand your's explanation. Sir, I followed these steps:- 1. downloaded springxd 1.3.0.

Comment: When you downloaded the zip, you then must have unzipped it someplace; let's say `/home/foo/spring-xd`. After unzipping you would have a directory: `/home/foo/spring-xd/spring-xd-1.3.0.RELEASE/`. That directory has a subdirectory `xd` and __that__ is where you need to put the script, under `xd/modules/processor/scripts/`.

Comment: I did the same. but still got error. without script i am able to create stream and able to post data also. means for stream definition http| cassandra it works fine. but with http|transformscript.groovy|cassandra it gives error.

Comment: It must be something simple; did you change the `XD_HOME` environment variable? `cd` into `spring-xd-1.3.0.RELEASE` and type `tree xd/modules/processor/` - edit the question with the results.

Comment: Can you try the simple stream/script in my answer?